# Facebook credits callback request is not always including the 'order_info' parameter

Tags: callback, facebook-credits

I have successful FB Credits integration, which receives many requests per day. But sometimes 3 or 4 times a day, my callback receives a 'payments_get_items' without the 'order_info' parameter.

Anybody has had the same problem? Or knows which cases could generate that kind of request? I am wondering if I can simply ignore the error.

Comment: Can you post the `order_id`(s) that don't have the `order_info` parameter? Are you positive you're passing a valid and complete `order_info` parameter from your front-end call to the callback?

Comment: Or better yet, if you can show me what is returned in the complete and incomplete requests that would be even better.

Comment: @DSchultz thanks for looking into this! I realized that there was a JavaScript bug on my side for IE7 and IE6 that was not setting the order_info parameter correctly, before doing the FBC API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an implementation error, which was no setting the order_info parameter correctly on some browsers. Seems that order_info is not mandatory at all, which makes sense to simplify its use.